# reference error of a specific function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using js codes to apply shadow . When my button background color is white it doesnot apply any box shadow.But one of my function is within uncaught reference error.

### My js files are

```
var btnDefault = $(".btn");
btnDefault.each(function(index, elem) {

    var btnDefaultbgColor = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    hexConvert(btnDefaultbgColor);
    if (color === '#ffffff' || color === '#fff') {
        $(this).css({
            'box-shadow': 'none'
        });
    };
});
```

### and my `hexConvert` function is

```
function hexConvert(colorval) {
    var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    if (!parts) {
        return null;
    }
    delete(parts[0]);
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
        parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
        if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
    }
    color = '#' + parts.join('');
}
```

There might be a issue with `background:transperent` (i am not understandin :/).
But when the background is white it also shows same error

How can i solve it?

Comment: What is the exact error? Have you included the script with the `hexConvert` function *before* you call it from the `$.each()`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The hexConvert is hoisted (http://jsbin.com/lidesecoqa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: try background-color instead of backgroundColor

Comment: also I believe color will be in the form 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', not in hex

Comment: Are you sure `parseInt` never gets anything as `parts[i]` that can't be parsed ? Also, why are you deleting `parts[0]` ?

Answer (score 1):

I see quite a few potential problems in your code. Not all of them are relevant to the specific symptom that you're asking about but nevertheless they may cause other problems now or in the future.

First, to convert the color value to hexadecimal format you call the hexConvert function solely for its side effects. That function doesn't return any value (at least most of the time, unless it returns null - see below) but rather sets a global `color` variable that is then read by other parts of your code.

Then, you use a sparse array `parts` with first element removed and then you join its elements to form a final value.

You return `null` in your `hexConvert` function but you never test its return value after the function call.

In case you don't have a match in `hexConvert` you return `null` but you still leave the previous value in the `color` global variable - which will be used after the call to `hexConvert` in the rest of your code every time the regex doesn't match - unless its the first call to this function, in which case the `color` will be undefined or will possibly have some other value set by some other parts of your code.

You assume that the color is going to be in the format `rgb(r, g, b)` and if so why won't you compare it to `rgb(255, 255, 255)` directly to check if it's white?

You don't say what error do you actually get and in what line, and seeing how many other possible problems are present in your code, it's really hard to give you any more precise answer.

Please post a working example in [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/), [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io/).

Comment: Hey i need to use that function here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nqj7xgdj/

Comment: @MusaMuaz This fiddle doesn't do anything. You just copied the code from your question but you don't have any HTML for it to work with, you don't load jQuery etc. You need to make the fiddle actually do anything and say what you get and what you expect before anyone will be able to help you. Why do you say that you need to use that function, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to convert from rgb to hex that I made some time ago... I hope it works better than yours:

```
var RgbToHex = function (string) {
    if( /rgba?\(0,0,0,0\)/.test(string.replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '')) ){
        return "transparent";
    }
    var v = string.replace(/[rgb|ba()]/g, "").split(",");
    var hex0 = parseInt(v[0]).toString(16);
    var hex1 = parseInt(v[1]).toString(16);
    var hex2 = parseInt(v[2]).toString(16);
    return ('#' + (hex0.length == 1 ? "0" + hex0 : hex0).toString() + (hex1.length == 1 ? "0" + hex1 : hex1).toString() + (hex2.length == 1 ? "0" + hex2 : hex2).toString()).toLocaleUpperCase();
}
```

[Check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/87sdr1mw/)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: string is not defined` in console

Comment: You have to pass a parameter to the function, like `RgbToHex('rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)) // returns #000000`. This method requires a parameter, else it can't convert nothing. Please, check the jsFiddle.